# PM2 in cluster mode throws bad option error for --harmony-async-await

Tags: node.js, pm2

I use nvm to mange my node versions, one is v6.10.1, one is v7.7.4. In normal times, PM2 works normally when I use the fork mode of PM2. Today, when I want to use the cluster mode of PM2, a bug occurred that I can not fix.

```
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.10.1/bin/node: bad option: --harmony-async-await
```

But I have told nvm to use v7.7.4 before **pm2 start process.json** and I defined **'/root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.4/bin/node'** for **'interpreter'** in the process file of pm2.

```
"interpreter": "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v7.7.4/bin/node", 
"node_args" : "--harmony-async-await",
```

So, why it happened? I need someone to help me. Tanks!

Comment: sorry, the title of question is wrong. Don't care

Answer (score -1):

I have solved the problem, thanks

```
rm -rf ~/.pm2
```

Comment: that's rather extreme